# Creating a gridview of images' thumbnails that expands when tapped in Android

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

I would like to create a gridview of images, in which, these images will be downloaded based on a web service response.

The thumbnails of images will be displayed in a gridview, similar to how iPhone displays photos.

User can tap on the image and the corresponding full-res image will be shown, sized to fit within the android phone. Upon tapping on the full-res image, it will minimize and return to the gridview.

So far, following the [guide](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views) here, I had manage to create the gridview of images, but I would like to have it expand to the original size upon tapping and tapping again, return to the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

See the Gallery, maybe all you need to do is change the OnItemClick behaviour.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html